# How do I programmatically change text attributes in a WebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I need to highlight certain segments of text within a WebView.  Until now, I've been doing this by injecting javascript into the webview using [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jscript].  The javascript adds a  tag to the text in which I change the background color to yellow.  This usually works but sometimes I corrupt the html when the  tag is inserted.  I would rather use the - (void)changeAttributes:(id)sender method on WebView, which, as I understand, will apply the style in a way that won't break the underlying html.  To do this I first call

```
[webView searchFor:aString direction:YES caseSensitive:NO wrap:YES];
```

To set the selection in the webview.  Then I call

```
[webView changeAttributes:self];
```

When I send this message to my WebView instance, it invokes this method:

```
- (NSDictionary *)convertAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
   NSMutableDictionary *newAttrs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributes];
   NSColor *background = [NSColor yellowColor];
   [newAttrs setValue:background forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];
   return newAttrs;
```

}

Which should change the background color of the selected text to yellow, but it does not. Do standard Cocoa text attributes apply to a webview? Is this method intended to be used for this purpose, or should I go back to javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These attributes are those for `NSFonts`. As described in [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000383-CJBGGDAI), the sequence of events is usually this:

1. `[text/webView changeAttributes:obj]` is performed. Usually it's done by `obj` itself.
2. `text/webView` passes the font attributes to `obj` using `[obj convertAttributes:...]`.
3. `obj` returns the attributes as it wants.
4. `text/webView` sets the font attributes accordingly.

Anyway I won't recommend this approach. I assume you're on OS X, not on iOS. Then, I would suggest you to get the DOM elements using `WebFrame`'s [`DOMDocument`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebFrame_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001895-BAJFBGIB) and set the styles directly.

Comment: You're right, doing this through the DOM is working better for me, but I found a better javascript solution:  document.designMode = \"on\";document.execCommand(\"backcolor\", false, \"yellow\");document.designMode = \"off\";